# Erro ao executar rotina de testes no NUnit por prompt de comando

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados, nunit

O seguinte erro é apresentado ao executar o comando:

```
NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException : The path specified in --result TestResult.xml could not be written to
  ----> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Windows\System32\TestResult.xml' foi negado.

--NUnitEngineException
The path specified in --result TestResult.xml could not be written to
   em NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunner.RunTests(TestPackage package, TestFilter filter)
   em NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Program.Main(String[] args)
--
UnauthorizedAccessException
O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Windows\System32\TestResult.xml' foi negado.
   em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   em System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   em NUnit.Engine.Services.NUnit3XmlResultWriter.WriteResultFile(XmlNode resultNode, String outputPath)
   em NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunner.RunTests(TestPackage package, TestFilter filter)
```

O caminho do arquivo .dll do teste está correto, mas o teste não é executado. Como soluciono este erro?

Comment: pelo erro parece ser um problema de autorização pra escrita (tentar escrever algo no system32 é meio esquisito mesmo), mas acredito que vá resolver se você abrir o cmd como admin

Comment: Como mencionado o erro é de permissão... mas porque diabos você está querendo escrever o testresult nesse diretório?

Comment: Não fui eu quem "diabos" configurei este caminho. O NUnit ja definiu como padrão. 
O comando --work= pode ser usado pra definir a pasta de destino. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O comando --work= pode ser usado para definir o caminho de destino onde o NUnit irá salvar o arquivo de teste. O prompt de comando fica assim:

```
nunit3-console C:\Users\bruno.silva\Desktop\ProjetoTeste\bin\Debug\ProjetoTeste.dll --work=C:\Users\bruno.silva\Desktop\ProjetoTeste\Output\TestResult.xml
```